# What should your weights look like if your Y variable needs transforming?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, weighted-regression

Using weights in regression models is kind of a new concept for me, and I'm confused about when and how I should use them correctly when I'm working with non-normal data.

Let's say I have a dependent variable, `Y1`. `Y1` is a proportion, but it's normally distributed around 0.6 and very few points approach either 0 or 1. The denominator of `Y1` varies considerably, from as low as 10 to maybe 600, and this variation co-varies with my independent variable of interest, `X1`, such that "treatment individuals" have lower `Y1` denominators and "control individuals" have higher ones. So, I run a regression `Y1 ~ X1, weights = denominator of Y1`, and this takes care of the unbalanced denominators in `Y1` conservatively (I think). So far, so good (I hope--please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Now to my question. Let's say we now have two other dependent variables, `Y2` and `Y3`. `Y2` is a ratio, and it's distributed in such a way that it would need to be log-transformed to be linearly regressed against `X1`. `Y3` is a proportion, and it would similarly need to be logit-transformed to be linearly regressed against `X1`. They both have denominators that similarly co-vary with `X1`, so it seems like weights are necessary. If I wanted to run a regression of the form of either `log(Y2) ~ X1` or `logit(Y3) ~ X1`, what should my weights look like? Should they be the transformed denominator or the untransformed denominator? Or, if the resulting `Y` variables are now normally distributed, more or less, are the weights no longer necessary at all? Or is it even wrong to use weights, once you've transformed your ratio/proportion?

I don't have much math background, so a more "practical" answer would be more useful to me than a more "theoretical" answer. Thanks!